# CentOS 7 looses network connection intermittently

Tags: networking, centos-7

I have CentOS 7 (minimal) running on a mac mini (2011).

I use it as a backend for my Plex Media Server & co., and today while watching a movie it lost its network connection.

I couldn't ping the machine and I couldn't ssh into it. But the machine was still running (according to the light on the mac mini).

A hard reboot, and everything was normal again.

As a *nix-beginner, how do I troubleshoot this issue? Where do I start? What logs are available to me?

I know about `journalctl`, but not really how to use it.

Any advice is much appreciated!

Edit:
Here's what I think are the relevant parts of `/var/log/messages`:

https://gist.github.com/BeyondEvil/0bdc94d942e367be676abb022b5a4a96

But what does it mean?

Edit2:
I guess what I first have to determine if this is related to the NFS share.

Given that this happened while using Plex and the "error" (pms kernel: nfs: server qnap not responding, still trying), it's not unlikely that this is the root cause.

The NFS server is running on a QNAP Nas, and I tried inspecting `/var/log/messages` but it was empty. And I've failed to find any other logs.

I use autofs for the mounting, and I have an `auto.nfs` file which is linked from `auto.master` with the contents:

`Movies -fstype=nfs,defaults qnap:/Movies`

`Series -fstype=nfs,defaults qnap:/Series`

`Music  -fstype=nfs,defaults qnap:/Music`

Maybe there are better suited settings for me to use than "defaults", for my use case?

What I've done so far is to make sure that both the QNAP and the CentOS server use (self-managed) static IPs. They used to be managed by the router.

Comment: Jimbro..... Read over this per the top error of the linked logs you provided.... https://access.redhat.com/solutions/28211 .... this gives steps to troubleshoot and other detail you potentially could find helpful. You'll have to dig to determine the root cause but based on 30 seconds of research, 15 seconds to read your post, and 15 seconds to write this comment, this is my one minute sprinkle of dust on the matter.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT - your comment offers no insite into the problem or solution, but pretends the problem is trivial and solved - and this is not at all apparent from the post - but cleary your answer is incorrect.

Comment: I could be wrong -  but from the log, it almost looks like a driver or network card problem which is causing the (broadcom tg3 - line 56 ) network interface to loose connectivity and then spit the dummy.   (It might have been a corrupt data packet + firmware or hardware bug).  The problem looks very much like its "nothing you did", but some kind of deficiency - as evidenced by the stack trace.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I have to dig a little deeper and try to see if the root cause is the NFS.

Comment: @davidgo Searching for line 23 gives me a lot of reported kernel bugs. Not sure what I'm supposed to do next. :(

Comment: @davidgo Yes, it was  just a "comment" and "potentially could be helpful" for a starting point. I didn't dig and spent very little time just as I indicated and then had to run off but that's what I gave for a simple starting point. In some cases DavidGo, it seems questions like "please troubleshoot and solve my problem" are not different than "write me this script" and showing no effort being put in yet. Word for word I was not trying to be "correct" or offer anything but "potential" starting point helpers for more effort from the OP to dig, dig, dig for troubleshooting 101 advice.

Comment: @davidgo Did you mean ["Insight"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insight) rather.... Jimbo - Yes sir I agree!! Dig, dig, dig!!! Never stop!!

Comment: I posit that NFS not responding is a symptom, not a cause. If ping is not working the problem is lower in the network stack, and focussing on NFS unlikely to help. I would see if there is any connectivity when the problem happens (eg ping the gateway), then unplug and replug network cable, restart networking, sop networking and remove & reinsert tg3 driver.

Comment: @davidgo Yeah, that probably makes sense. So when it failed, the CentOS machine (mac mini, running PMS etc) was unreachable. No ping no ssh. Hard reboot solved it. Next time it happens I'll try your suggestions. Problem is the machine has no keyboard or display. But I'll have to sort that out. What does "sop networking" mean (and how do I do it?) and how do I remove/reinsert tg3 driver? :)

Comment: @davidgo I just realized something else. This started happening after I did a "yum update". Is there a log for the latest update? Maybe something got updated and had a bug/regression?

Comment: @davidgo lol, it just happened again. unplug/replug network cable gave me access again (after a minute or two).

Comment: Someone directed me to this: https://github.com/elatov/elatov.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2018-02-10-troubleshooting-tg3-driver-issues-on-macmini-running-coreos.md There's also a bug reported over at centosproject regarding this. I'm trying the workaround with the dongle/adapter. Let's see how it holds up. :-/